# django sqlite strftime & parametric SQL query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a **django** based web application doing, among others, analyses of time histories. I am currently using **sqlite** as db backend.

I typically group slices of data in blocks of ten minutes, thus I aggregate to get my final results.

To obtain ten minutes blocks of data I have the following queryset

```
blocks = qs.extra({'ten_min' : u"strftime('%Y%m%d%H0', date) + strftime('%M', date)/10"})\
        .values('ten_min').annotate(mop.Sum('event_val1'),mop.Sum('event_val2')).all()
```

which I also possibly restrict on given time intervals, e.g.

```
qs.get(date__gte = last_midnight)
```

While the two queries work perfectly while separated, **they do not work chained**.

The final parametric SQL query string that django generates cannot be rendered as the `%` in the `strtftime` of sqlite are misinterpreted as element to be replaced while rendering the string.

Let me report the entire query for clarity:

```
params = (u"'2016-10-06 00:00:44.054382'",)
sql =   u'SELECT (strftime(\'%Y%m%d%H0\', date) + strftime(\'%M\', date)/10) AS "ten_min", SUM("event_logger_event"."event_val1") AS "event_val1__sum", SUM("event_logger_event"."event_val2") AS "event_val2__sum" FROM "event_logger_event" WHERE "event_logger_event"."date" >= %s GROUP BY (strftime(\'%Y%m%d%H0\', date) + strftime(\'%M\', date)/10)'
```

the query is rendered as `sql % params` which gives an error.

In fact the system tries to replace elements such as `%Y%m%d` rather than the correct

```
... "date" >= %s ...
```

Any suggestion on how to deal with this?

Comment: You probably need to double the % characters: `'%%Y%%m%%d%%H0'`

Comment: let me give a try

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks! that worked. Kept me busy for the last couple of hours. :)